# How can I get a daily hour value from a date/time field?

Tags: calculated-column, date-time

I am trying to calculate the amount of time on a daily basis.

Currently I have calculated "[**total hours per diem**]", "[**total days**]" and the time values (if not split over multiple days).

Where I am having trouble is in calculating the total time spent if the event is not an "all day event" and falls over multiple days.

For example:

If I had **1/1/2013 12:00 PM** (Start Date) and **1/2/2013 4:00 PM** (End date).  I would like to have the result be 8 hours ((4 hours per day day) * (2 days)).  What I actually end up with is 28 hours (the difference between the two times).

It should be something like =([**total days**]*(*time difference of **end time - start time**)) but I can't figure out how to just pull the time for a single day.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
var startDate = Convert.ToDateTime("1/1/2013 12:00 PM");
var endDate = Convert.ToDateTime("1/2/2013 4:00 PM");

var diffHours = (endDate.Hour - startDate.Hour);
```